# Transforming CSV to multiple formats using python

Tags: python

I have a CSV file which needs to be transformed for two different purposes.

1. for Event booklet printing ( Day wise schedule sorted by time)
   16/11/2017 (Thursday)
   Time, Vocal/Violin/Mrudagam ( If Event is 'Vocal')
   Time, Dance/Violin/Mrudangam (If Event is 'Dance')
   Time, Drama  ( if Event is 'Drama')
2. for Firebase upload ( JSON )

Date,Time,Event,Vocal,Violin,Mrudangam,Ghatam,Kanjira,Bharatanatyam,Dance,Flute, Drama

Not all columns will have values for all rows.  For example, if the event is a 'VOCAL' then only 'Vocal', 'Violin' and 'Mrudangam' will have values.

I read the CSV file and sort the same using

```
with open(args.eventfile,'r') as csvfile:
    eventreader = csv.DictReader(csvfile, delimiter=",")
    #sortedlist = sorted(eventreader, key=lambda row:(row['Date'],row['Time']), reverse=False)
    sortedlist = sorted(eventreader, key=lambda each_dict: (datetime.strptime(each_dict['Date'], '%m/%d/%Y'),
                          datetime.strptime(each_dict['Time'], '%I:%M %p')))
```

and then process every row, like so,

```
def form_event_string(event):
    fevent=""
    print("formatting event: " + event['Event'])
    if event['Event'] == 'VOCAL':
        fevent = "{Vocal}/{Violin}/{Veena}/{Mrudangam}/{Ghatam}/{Kanjira}/{Morsing}/{Flute}/{Other}/{Venue}".format(**event)
    elif event['Event'] == 'VIOLIN':
        fevent = "{Violin}/{Mrudangam}/{Ghatam}/{Kanjira}".format(**event)
    elif event['Event'] == 'VEENA':
        fevent = "{Veena}/{Flute}/{Violin}/{Mrudangam}/{Ghatam}/{Kanjira}/{Morsing}/{GottuVadhyam}".format(**event)
    elif event['Event'] == 'GHATAM':
        fevent = "{Ghatam}/{Violin}/{Mrudangam}/{Kanjira}/{Morsing}".format(**event)
    else event['Event'] == 'BHARATANATYAM':
        fevent = "{Bharatanatyam}".format(**event)
return fevent
```

and keep appending this string into a CSV file.

My question is - is there a different way to get this done?  Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There is a much better way! Pandas! just transform the csv as a data frame and you can create a column using a custom function with new_column = df['column'].apply(function). Afterwards you can save the df as a json. 
http://pandas.pydata.org